# FFMPEG: How to save the effects (blur, adding image , ...) on the input video instead of creating a one?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I need to save the effects on the current video instead of creating a one. For example this code

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]scale2ref=(505/384)*ih/8:ih/8[wm][base];[wm]setsar=1[wmsar];[base][wmsar]overlay=10:10" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy output.mp4`

pastes an image on a video, but I need the image to be pasted to `input.mp4` not `output.mp4`.

I tried

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]scale2ref=(505/384)*ih/8:ih/8[wm][base];[wm]setsar=1[wmsar];[base][wmsar]overlay=10:10" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a`

but it didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FFmpeg does not do in-place editing. Target has to be new file.

Comment: What's the problem with ffmpeg -i input [..] output && mv output input? This has the additional advantage that if the conversion fails for whatever reason, the input will be preserved unmodified.

Comment: @RonaldS.Bultje because I am building an online video editor and a sequence of effects must be applied to a video. For example for 10 effects, 10 new video are going to be created and the user must do 10 delete operations